# Trying to delete specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$('.icn-trash').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteBookmark($('.del').data('bookmarkid'));
});

function deleteBookmark(bookmarkID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/BookmarkApi/delete/' + bookmarkID,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            $('.icn-trash').closest('.del').remove();
            console.log('removed');
        },
        error: function(error) {

        }
    });
}
```

HTML - it will be generated dynamically for every bookmark folder.

```
<a href="#" class="del" data-bookmarkid="xxx">

<span class="actions" style="z-index:300">
  <i class="icn-trash"></i>
</span>

</a>
```

Everytime, I try to delete the specific id of the bookmark folder, multiple folders are removed. It should only remove one specific folder when clicking trash icon. When I clicked trash icon on 6th folder, the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th folders will disappear and i refreshed again only to find 1st folder actually being removed from database.

I want to have 6th folder disappear and removed from database.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
   $(document).on('click', '.icn-trash',function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var b_id=$(this).closest('.del').data('bookmarkid')
        $.ajax({
            url: '/BookmarkApi/delete/' + b_id,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                $(this).closest('.del').remove();
                console.log('removed');
            },
            error: function(error) {

            }
        });

});
```

Comment: tried your example, but it becomes a link returning the bookmarked images, not remove the folder.

Comment: cant use  $(this).closest('.del').remove(); because the folder will not disappear. only after i refresh it disappears

Comment: Click trash text not click text,its working.target is trash ok

Answer (score 0):

I would bind the event on the a tag:

```
$('.del').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteBookmark(this);
});

function deleteBookmark(ele) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/BookmarkApi/delete/' + $(ele).data('bookmarkid'),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            $(ele).remove();
            console.log('removed');
        },
        error: function(error) {

        }
    });
}
```

---

Or if you still want to bind on `.icn-trash`:

```
$('.icn-trash').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteBookmark($(this).closest('.del'));
});

function deleteBookmark(ele) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/BookmarkApi/delete/' + ele.data('bookmarkid'),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            ele.remove();
            console.log('removed');
        },
        error: function(error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: yours works but unfortunately i dont want the whole del to be clicked for delete only. it will be also a link if the user clicks on thumbnails.

Comment: @kittymeows You could bind on `.icn-trash ` as you wish, see the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing content using class attribute that return collection of all the links and remove the links.

```
  $('.icn-trash').on('click', function (e) {
                    debugger
                    event.preventDefault()
                    deleteBookmark(this);
                });

          function deleteBookmark(obj) {
                debugger
                bookmarkID = $('.del').data('bookmarkid');
              $(obj).remove();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/BookmarkApi/delete ,
 data: { bookmarkID: bookmarkID},
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (response) {

                        console.log('removed');
                    },
                    error: function (error) {

                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Sorry to let u know that only trash icon disappears when click on that icon.

Comment: Ajax request is not proper fired now do check it.

Comment: yes i checked but it doesnt make folder disappear. only icon disappear.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery Documentation of [closest API](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Now what is happening in the code `$('.icn-trash').closest('.del').remove();`

`$(.icn-trash')` is returning the set of all element elements having the class `icn-trash`. And then you are using this set to find the closest element with class `.del` which will return a set of all anchor tags (in your html example). Finally you are removing the entire set. Hence multiple bookmarks are getting deleted.

I am assuming you need to delete the anchor tag which has the `data-bookmarkid` as bookmarkID

```js
$('.icn-trash').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteBookmark($('.del').data('bookmarkid'));
});

function deleteBookmark(bookmarkID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/BookmarkApi/delete/' + bookmarkID,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            // get the element with data-bookmarkid = bookmarkID and remove it
            $("[data-bookmarkid='" + bookmarkID + "']").remove()
            console.log('removed');
        },
        error: function(error) {

        }
    });
}
```

*EDIT:* I didn't read the last part of your question

> When I clicked trash icon on 6th folder, the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th folders will disappear and i refreshed again only to find 1st folder actually being removed from database.

Can you make sure that the bookmarkIds are correct in the data-bookmarkid attribute? Since clicking on 6th trash icon is removing the 1st folder from the database, there seems to be a problem either with your server code or the data-bookmarkid attribute is incorrect in the 6th trash icon

*EDIT2:* Why you are getting the wrong bookmarkId (Didn't investigat enough thoroughly earlier, got involved in  something else)

Again quoting from [jQuery documentation for data API](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)

> Return the value at the named data store for the *first element* in the jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value) or by an HTML5 data-* attribute.

So analyzing your code `deleteBookMark($('.del').data('bookmarkid'))`: $('.del') will contain all the elements with class name del (in your example all the anchor tags). Calling `.data('bookmarkid')` with the entire set will return the bookmark id of the first anchor tag. The best way to do this is to first obtain the element which was clicked. This can be done by modifying your code

Again from jQuery Documentation for Event Listener

> When jQuery calls a handler, the this keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered;...
>   To create a jQuery object from the element so that it can be used with jQuery methods, use $( this ).

This means that

```
$('.icn-trash').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  deleteBookmark($('.del').data('bookmarkid'));
});
```

In the listener you have attached, `this` will refer to the `.icn-trash` element you clicked on. So now you know which element was clicked, find the closest `.del` element and then get its data-bookmarkid attribute. i.e.

```
$('.icn-trash').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var curIconTrash = $(this),
       closestAnchor = curIconTrash.closest('.del'),
       bookMarkId = closestAnchor.data('bookmarkid')

   deleteBookmark(bookmarkId);
});
```

Or taking the advantage of [jQuery chaining](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/what-is-chaining-in-jquery.html)

```
$('.icn-trash').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   deleteBookmark($(this).closest('.del').data('bookmarkid'));
});
```

Note: This was also suggested by @sreedhar-r

Hope this helps! Cheers :-)

Comment: thanks for explaining in details and i appreciate it. the bookmarkids are correct as shown in the console.log. hmm. not sure where it goes wrong

Comment: @vuda - console.log($('.del').data('bookmarkid')); returns the bookmark id of the first folder. it should show the id of 6th folder. hmm